# Select data containing multiple words from IBM Db2 database

Tags: sql, database, db2

i want to select a specific data from my database based on the user input.

For example, in my database i've:

> **Commodity**
>
> Coats; men's or boys'
> Coats; women's or girls'

If a user searches for coats for men, the first result will be printed out.

My query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Commodity" 
FROM "PKD20375"."TRADES"
WHERE "Commodity" LIKE '%Coats%' AND "Commodity" LIKE '%men%';
```

But both results for men and women get printed out. I only need coats for men.

```
WHERE "Commodity" LIKE '%Coats men%';
```

This query also does not give the result. However, Coats;men works, but only the value coats and men should be used without the ;.
Any idea would really help. Thank you.

Comment: `WHERE "Commodity" LIKE '%Coats% men%'`?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Thanks a lot.

Comment: where commodity like '%coats% and commodity not like '%women%  keep with it.